# How do you extract view code to a Component in Volt

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I’m trying to extract some repeated view stuff into a component, in a similar way to a rails partial.

I want this:

```
{{ activity.each do |activity| }}
    <div class="{{ activity.style_class }}>
       {{ activity.text }}
    </div>
{{ end }}
```

To become this:

```
{{ activity.each do |activity| }}
    <:activity>
{{ end }}
```

But whenever I try to move my view code to `app/activity/views/main/index.html`
I get errors about activity not existing.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to pass in `model` when calling the component:

```
// app/main/views/main/index.html

{{ activity.each do |activity| }}
    <:activity model="{{ activity }}">
{{ end }}
```

Then in your component you scope it onto itself like this:

```
// app/activity/views/main/index.html

<div class="{{ style_class }}>
  {{ text }}
</div>
```

Comment: I think this should be model="{{ activity }}" /> instead of model: